# Can't deploy Android/Google Maps app from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm an android newbie having a lot of troubles with the android emulator.  I have inconsistent luck in starting up the emulator, and no luck if I start it from within eclipse instead of from the commandline (it waits forever and never boots -- not even after 24 hours).

However, since I figured out how to get it to (sometimes!) start from the command line, I have a workaround to that particular problem.  But I have no workaround for my latest problem.  When I try to run it:

`[2010-08-09 22:08:12 - MyApp] ------------------------------

[2010-08-09 22:08:12 - MyApp] Android Launch!

[2010-08-09 22:08:12 - MyApp] adb is running normally.

[2010-08-09 22:08:12 - MyApp] Performing com.android.MyApp.MyApp activity launch

[2010-08-09 22:08:12 - MyApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'TestDroid'

[2010-08-09 22:08:12 - MyApp] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!

[2010-08-09 22:08:12 - MyApp] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)

[2010-08-09 22:08:14 - MyApp] Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2010-08-09 22:08:14 - MyApp] Installing MyApp.apk...

[2010-08-09 22:08:15 - MyApp] Success!

[2010-08-09 22:08:15 - MyApp] Starting activity com.android.MyApp.MyApp on device`

But nothing starts on my android instance.  MyApp doesn't even show up on the app list.

I assume I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the adb logcat output, it might show some errors. Also, does your app specify a launcher Activity?

Comment: I'd like to look at the logcat output, but I had to restart my computer, and now I'm back to the old "making it boot" dilemma  :P  Argh.  Well, I'll try that whenever I can get it back up.

Here's my manifest:

<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><br>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.android.MyApp" android:versionCode="1"       android:versionName="1.0"><br>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"><br>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /><br>
</code>

Comment: <code>
    <activity android:name=".MyApp" android:label="@string/app_name"><br>
      <intent-filter><br>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><br>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /><br>
      </intent-filter><br>
    </activity><br>
  </application><br>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><br>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /><br>
</manifest><br>
</code>

Comment: try adb devices. Is the device or emulator detected? If not restart adb server. Else try adb logcat and see whats the error during boot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have fixed this by (possibly) resolving my emulator startup bug.

Comment: What do you mean by "resolving my emulator startup bug" - what was the bug?